# How a browser decides whether to send a http or https request?

Tags: google-chrome, http, ssl, https, hsts

I know in order for a browser to send an HTTPS request it must be either in the preloaded HSTS list
( or )
The site will be first requested in HTTP and the site will tell the browser the make an HTTPS request and now when the browser makes an HTTPS request, the site will send the HSTS header as a response which will be stored in the browser HSTS cache and now the browser will only make calls with HTTPS when the site is requested for a period of time as mentioned by the HSTS header response of the site.

I've tested this on chrome but the results are violating the above definition, I'll explain the test.

1. I've cleared the HSTS cache of this example site ' mail.zoho.com '  which I'm going to request in chrome by using this chrome URL:' chrome://net-internals/#hsts '.
2. I've also checked that this site is not preloaded in the HSTS list by checking here: https://hstspreload.org/
3. I'm making a call to this website ' mail.zoho.com ' and I monitored this using the network tab of chrome.

[The image of my network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzAql.jpg)

You can clearly see that chrome is making first an HTTPS request but it should only make an HTTP request first, right?  because I've cleared both the HSTS cache in chrome. How is this possible? Or Is there something I'm missing to learn?